# Android getMapAsync in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, dictionary, supportmapfragment

You need to get the map management in the fragment.

My code

```
public class Fragment1 extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback{

GoogleMap gm;

private void initializeMap() {
    if (gm == null) {
        SupportMapFragment mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapView);
        mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    gm = googleMap;
    setUpMap();
}

public void setUpMap()
{
    Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Map load!");
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    initializeMap();
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.need_help_view, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}
```

}

error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference
```

what is the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Obviously, there doesn't exist a fragment that is added with id `R.id.mapView`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are initializing map without even inflating the view....so your `mapFrag` is null.

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    initializeMap();
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.need_help_view, container, false);
}
```

Try this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.need_help_view, container, false);
    if (gm == null) {
        SupportMapFragment mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapView);
        mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);
    }
    return v;
}
```